# MySQL selecting range between data

Tags: mysql

So I have my columns listed as `10, 20, 30, 40, 50` and would like mySQL to select and round up numbers between two selected ranges. So for queries `BETWEEN 11 AND 32` I would like it to include the data between `10` and `40`.

As is, simply using `BETWEEN 11 AND 32` will only get me the values listed between `20-30`. Rounding to the nearest 10 also does not alleviate this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you want to `FLOOR()` on your min and `CEIL()` on your max value. Check out those functions in mysql and see if they help. You should be able to `FLOOR(11)` and `CEIL(32)` in your between

Comment: no, you can't. floor/ceil round up/down to integers.`floor(11)` **IS** `11`

Comment: The term "I would like to include the data between 10 and 40" is mathematically vague. You might be interested in an open interval ]10,40[ or a closed one [10, 40] (including or not including 10 and 40) or just including the lower [10,40[ or the upper border ]10,40]. Also I assume you list your rows , not your columns?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
BETWEEN (FLOOR(lower/10)*10) AND (CEIL(upper/10)*10)
```

with lower and upper to be integers like 11 and 32, which will result in

```
(FLOOR(11/10)*10) => (FLOOR(1.1)*10) => 1*10 => 10
(CEIL(32/10)*10) => (CEIL(3.2)*10) => 4*10 => 40
```

Answer (score 0):

`x BETWEEN y AND z` is the functional equivalent of `(y <= x) AND (x <= z)`. if you want records "outside" of the specified range, then you have to widen your range, or modify the out-of-range values to be IN range.